# Java Two-Dim Array

Tags: java

Please compare students grade as follow:
Student NO.: 25 31 6 78 42
Score: 78 85 63 59 99

Design a program, if a teacher input a score that the program would output:
(1) which student number higher than the score
(2) the total number of student higher the scores

e.g. INPUT: 80, it would output (1)student NO.31,42. (2) total:2 students

I think the problem is at "for loop" after the program running. I entered a score 80 it presents "NO. 25 Total 1, NO. 25 Total 2,....... NO. 25 Total 8"
It seems repeated situation and only catch first item student No.25.

Here is my code, please help me to correct it, thank you

```
public class TWOarray {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = new int[][] {
        {25, 31, 6, 78, 42},
        {78, 85, 63, 59, 99}
    };
    int count = 0;
    int yournum = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("ENTER score");
    yournum = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length;i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length-1;j++) {
        if (yournum >= arr[0][j]) {
          count++;
        } else if (yournum < arr[0][j]) {
        }
        System.out.print("student NO:" + arr[i][0] + "total" + count + "students");
      }         
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a homework reviewing service. You haven't even described what is wrong with your program that you think needs correcting.

Comment: Sorry, I think my problem is at "for loop" and how to set the item in for loop.

Comment: _please help me to correct it:_ You only gave us your homework, not the problem you have... Since you already have done something, when can help but you need to explain what is not working, I am not going to do a full test case for this

Comment: Please format your question better so we can understand your problem.

Comment: @khelwood I agree that, but _Not a homework reviewing service_ isn't true. This is not always a correct reason to refuse a question ( a lot of downvote here for bad reason I think)

Comment: @AxelH If someone posts their code, asks for it to be reviewed (and gives no detail about a specific issue they need help with), then they want a reviewing service, and it's not a proper question. I'm not saying that we never help anyone with a homework-related question. I'm saying we are not a homework reviewing service.

Comment: @khelwood you have made your point, I don't agree completly with it, there is some problem but for a first question, I could probably find a lot worst in recent question frim older users. What I mean is that for new users, we should redirect on the FAQ instead of simply downvoting them. Note : I am removing my older comments since this is a bit chatty ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is rookie  mistake.

In the following line

```
  for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length-1;j++) {
```

you will never check the last case of the row because the condition is `j < arr[i].length -1`, it is `j < arr[i].length` or `j <=  arr[i].length -1` to iterate every cells.

Then for the following block

```
if (yournum >= arr[0][j]) {
      count++;
} else if (yournum < arr[0][j]) {

}
System.out.print("student NO:" + arr[i][0] + "total" + count + "students");
```

Your are always using the first row in your table. Use `i` like `arr[i][j]`